# Load default on change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 options for an onchange event to open and hide radio button values. I am not sure how I can set the first one (value == 2) to already be opened on the page by default. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code I currently have.

```
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function () {
    $('.opening-fields').toggle(+this.value === 1 && this.checked);
    $('.qualify-fields').toggle(+this.value === 2 && this.checked);
    $('.verify-fields').toggle(+this.value === 3 && this.checked);
    $('.datasheet-fields').toggle(+this.value === 4 && this.checked);
}).change();
```

Comment: There is no reason why you need to bind the change event 3 separate times. You can combine the logic into one. To what kind of input elements are you binding the change event listener to? A select element? A text/numeric input?

Comment: You can set the default value in the html, did you try that?

Comment: We need to see your HTML to help you although it sounds like you just need to add a `checked` attribute on the relevant `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement to determine the value of the checked radio input... Then `.show()` the relevant element.

The one to be `checked` onload should have the `checked` attribute in the HTML.

I assumed all elements are hidden by default.... So I used the `hidden` class. This may be different in your code... That is just for the example.

```js
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function () {
  
  // Only for the checked input
  if(this.checked){
    // Hide them all
    $(".hidden").hide();

    // determine which to show
    switch(this.value){
      case "1":
        $('.opening-fields').show();
        break;
      case "2":
        $('.qualify-fields').show();
        break;
      case "3":
        $('.verify-fields').show();
        break;
      case "4":
        $('.datasheet-fields').show();
        break;
     }
  }
}).trigger("change"); // Trigger a change event Onload
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

1:<input type="radio" name="type" value="1"><br>
2:<input type="radio" name="type" value="2" checked><br> <!-- checked onload -->
3:<input type="radio" name="type" value="3"><br>
4:<input type="radio" name="type" value="4"><br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="opening-fields hidden">opening-fields</div>
<div class="qualify-fields hidden">qualify-fields</div>
<div class="verify-fields hidden">verify-fields</div>
<div class="datasheet-fields hidden">datasheet-fields</div>
```